# How can we determine the factorisation of $2\mathcal{O}_L$?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $L =\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{-3})$ and $ K = \Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$. Now the prime $2$ is totally ramified in two of the three subfields of $L$ and from ramification theory we know that $2$ splits as $P^2$ in $\mathcal{O}_L$. How can I determine the exact prime decomposition of $2\mathcal{O}_L$? I do this because I want to prove that every prime factor of $2\mathcal{O}_L$ is principal, thus showing that $\mathcal{O}_L$ is a PID (The minkowski bound is less than 3).

However my problem now is that the usual way to do this via factoring a certain polynomial mod $p$ does not work. To simplify this, I tried to see if I could factor the ideal $(\sqrt{2})$ of $\mathcal{O}_K$ in the bigger ring $\mathcal{O}_L$. However this is not so simple: we have

$$\operatorname{disc} \mathcal{O}_L = 16 \cdot 36$$

and $\operatorname{disc} \mathcal{O}_K[\sqrt{-3}] = (-96)^2 $ (this latter calculation was done [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=det%28%7B%7B1,Sqrt%5B2%5D,Sqrt%5B-3%5D,Sqrt%5B-6%5D%7D,%20%7B1,-Sqrt%5B2%5D,Sqrt%5B-3%5D,-Sqrt%5B-6%5D%7D,%20%7B1,Sqrt%5B2%5D,-Sqrt%5B-3%5D,-Sqrt%5B-6%5D%7D,%7B1,-Sqrt%5B2%5D,-Sqrt%5B-3%5D,Sqrt%5B-6%5D%7D%7D%29)) and thus the index $$\left[\mathcal{O}_L : \mathcal{O}_K[\sqrt{-3}] \right] = 4.$$

Since $2|4$ I can't apply the usual procedure even to factoring $\sqrt{2}$ in $\mathcal{O}_L$.

> > **My question is:** How can I find the exact factorisation of $2\mathcal{O}_L$?  More generally how can I find the factorisation of prime ideals when the usual process does not work?

Thanks.

Comment: There is an algorithm of Buchmann and H.W. Lenstra. It always works. It is described in Cohen's book. But it's no fun to do it by hand.

Comment: @HansGiebenrath If I had SAGE I could do it, but I would like a computation by hand.

Comment: 2 is not ramified in the subfield $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$.

Comment: May I suggest you edit the title of your question? The current title is a question that's different from the one you want an answer to.

Comment: @DaanMichiels I have edited my title.

Comment: @Ted Sorry I was wrong about that subfield. I have now edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $e$, $f$, and $g$ be the usual prime splitting parameters for 2 in the extension $L$. Looking at how 2 splits in ${\mathbf Q}(\sqrt{2})$ shows $2|e$. Looking at how 2 splits in ${\mathbf Q}(\sqrt{-3})$ shows $2|f$. Since $efg = 4$, we must have $e = 2, f = 2$, and $g = 1$. Thus $2{\mathcal O}_L = {\mathfrak p}_4^2$, where ${\mathfrak p}_4$ is a prime ideal in ${\mathcal O}_L$ of norm 4. But also $2{\mathcal O}_L = (\sqrt{2}{\mathcal O}_L)^2$, so $(\sqrt{2}{\mathcal O}_L)^2 = {\mathfrak p}_4^2$. By unique factorization, ${\mathfrak p}_4 = \sqrt{2}{\mathcal O}_L$ is principal.

This is simply saying that the prime over 2 in ${\mathbf Q}(\sqrt{2})$ stays prime in ${\mathbf Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{-3}) = {\mathbf Q}(\sqrt{2},\zeta_3)$, which in retrospect is clear since the residue field at $(\sqrt{2})$ in ${\mathbf Q}(\sqrt{2})$ is ${\mathbf F}_2$ and $x^2 + x + 1$ - the minimal polynomial of $\zeta_3$ over ${\mathbf Q}(\sqrt{2})$ - is irreducible over ${\mathbf F}_2$. That is, if you'd think of $L$ as ${\mathbf Q}(\sqrt{2})(\zeta_3) = K(\zeta_3)$, a quadratic extension of $K$, and ${\mathcal O}_L$ as the integral closure of ${\mathcal O}_K$ in $L$, then you can use the *same* methods to factor $\sqrt{2}{\mathcal O}_K$ in ${\mathcal O}_L$ as you'd use to factor a rational prime in a quadratic field.  After all, $K$ has class number 1, just like ${\mathbf Q}$. When you write that the "usual" methods don't work, it's not true! You need to think of number fields in a relative way, one number field as an extension of another, instead of everything as an extension of ${\mathbf Q}$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When you write about field extensions relative to one another, that's what I considered in my question above. For example, I wanted to determine the splitting of $\sqrt{2}\mathcal{O}_K$ in $\mathcal{O}_L$. However the index $[ \mathcal{O}_L : \mathcal{O}_K[\sqrt{-3}] ]$ being $4$ did not allow me to do this since $2 | 4$. By the usual process, I mean I am applying Theorem 27 of Marcus' *Number Fields*.

Comment: @BenjaLim I don't have that book, and maybe there are some special conditions in that theorem, but why are you using $\mathcal{O}_K[\sqrt{-3}]$ instead of $\mathcal{O}_K[\zeta_3]$?  It seems like you should use the latter because it's the largest "obvious" set of algebraic integers in $L$.

Comment: @Ted I am very stupid and forgot that we can write $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{-3}) = \Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\zeta_3)$.

Comment: @Ted I have posted an answer below.

Comment: @KCd I have posted an answer below clarifying what I understand of the problem.

Comment: Don't use the integral index $[{\mathcal O}_L:{\mathcal O}_K[\zeta_3]]$, but the ${\mathbf Z}[\sqrt{2}]$-index. If $A$ is a PID and $M$ is a finite free $A$-module with $N$ a submodule of equal rank, which makes $M/N$ a f.g. torsion $A$-module, there is a notion of $A$-index $[M:N]_A$: let $M/N = \oplus_{k=1}^d A/(a_k)$, a direct sum of cyclic modules. This is not canonical, but the *product ideal* $(a_1\cdots a_k)$ is well-defined (indep. of the direct sum decomposition). This ideal in $A$ is the $A$-index of $N$ in $M$. When $A = {\mathbf Z}$, so $M/N$ is finite, it is $\#(M/N){\mathbf Z}$.

Comment: If ${\mathcal O}_K$ is a PID then the whole "usual" theory of discriminants carries over to finite extensions $L/K$ (all ${\mathcal O}_K$-bases of ${\mathcal O}_L$ have discriminant over $K$ that is equal up to unit multiple, so there is a well-defined principal ideal ${\rm disc}_{{\mathcal O}_K}({\mathcal O}_L)$ made from any such basis.) Then if $L = K(\gamma)$ for $\gamma \in {\mathcal O}_L$, we have ${\rm disc}_{{\mathcal O}_K}({\mathcal O}_K[\gamma]) = [{\mathcal O}_L:{\mathcal O}_K[\gamma]]_{{\mathcal O}_K}^2{\rm disc}_{{\mathcal O}_K}({\mathcal O}_L)$ as ideals. If LHS (cont...)

Comment: is squarefree ideal then the index $[{\mathcal O}_L:{{\mathcal O}_K}[\gamma]]_{{\mathcal O}_K}$ is the unit ideal (1), and by the definition of the ${\mathcal O}_K$-index this implies (and in fact is equivalent to) ${\mathcal O}_L = {\mathcal O}_K[\gamma]$. There is a general notion of discriminant ideal for any relative extension of number fields, but the point here is that when the bottom ring is a PID you don't need to develop that very general theory and can quickly (?) use ideas from the integers if you make the right  extension of concepts from base ring ${\mathbf Z}$ to PID base ring.

Comment: @KCd Thanks for your comments. I will look up the notion of relative indices in your notes.

Answer (score 0):

As in my question I would like to determine how $\sqrt{2}$ splits in the $\mathcal{O}_L = \Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{2},\alpha]$ where $\alpha = \frac{1 + \sqrt{-3}}{2}$. Now consider the composite

$$ \Bbb{Z}[\alpha] \to \Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{2},\alpha] \to \Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{2},\alpha]/(\sqrt{2}).$$

The kernel of this composite contains $(2)$ and now I claim it is exactly that: For the quotient $$\Bbb{Z}[\alpha]/(2) \cong \Bbb{Z}[x]/(x^2 - x + 1, 2) \cong \Bbb{F}_4$$

which is the field with four elements. Since the composite I wrote above is not the zero map, we get that the kernel is exactly $(2)$. Now $\Bbb{F}_4$ is a field and so $\sqrt{2}\mathcal{O}_L$ is maximal. In particular this means that $\sqrt{2}\mathcal{O}_K$ is inert in $\mathcal{O}_L$.

Comment: First you should prove ${\mathcal O}_L$ equals ${\mathbf Z}[\sqrt{2},\zeta_3]$. (Why use $\alpha = \zeta_3 + 1$ instead of $\zeta_3$ in this problem?) Treating ${\mathbf Z}[\sqrt{2},\zeta_3]$ as a ${\mathbf Z}[\sqrt{2}]$-module, its ${\mathbf Z}[\sqrt{2}]$-discriminant is the ideal $(-3){\mathbf Z}[\sqrt{2}]$, which is prime (since 3 is inert), hence squarefree, so the ${\mathbf Z}[\sqrt{2}]$-index $[{\mathcal O}_L:{\mathbf Z}[\sqrt{2}][\zeta_3]]$ is the unit ideal $(1)$, and thus ${\mathcal O}_L$ is what you want. Then $x^2+x+1$ being  irred. over ${\mathbf Z}[\sqrt{2}]/(\sqrt{2})$ (contd...)

Comment: makes $\sqrt{2}{\mathcal O}_L$ prime in ${\mathcal O}_L$.

Comment: @KCd Thanks for your response. I can prove that $\mathcal{O}_L$ equals $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{2},\zeta_3]$ using traces, but I have not seen the approach in your comment above.

Comment: @BenjaLim per request I converted your answer to Wiki. But for future reference, note that you can do it yourself for **answers**. At the bottom of the edit box there is a tick-box that allows you to turn any of your answers into CW. It is only **questions** that requires moderator handling.

Comment: @WillieWong I don't seem to see any tick-box that allows me to make my answer into CW.  Do you have a screenshot/metalink of how I can do this? Thanks.

Comment: @BenjaLim http://math.stackexchange.com/privileges/community-wiki

Comment: If you mean for the current answer, once you change to CW, you can't go back. Hence you won't see the tickbox on an already CW'd answer.